# Stable deconvolution of a band-limited function from its convolution with a Gaussian

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform, inverse-problems

Suppose that $f : \mathbb R \to \mathbb C$ is a band-limited function, i.e. its Fourier transform $\hat f$ has support in a compact interval $[-a,a]$. Let $\phi(t) = e^{-\frac{t^2}{2\sigma^2}}$ be a Gaussian with variance $\sigma^2$. Further, let
$$
F= f* \phi
$$
be the convolution of $f$ with $\phi$. Is there a way to stably reconstruct $f$ from $F$? Intuitively if $a$ and $\sigma$ are both small then the deconvolution should be more stable. Are there any results about stability and reconstruction procedures of this inverse problem?

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Could you explain exactly what "stable" means here? Intuitively it is clear that stability (whatever it means) depends also on $a$ not only on $\sigma$.

Comment: The inverse of F has an explicit formula via Fourier transform. It is straightforward to calculate the operator norm of the inverse (e.g. in the setting where F maps from L² to L²).